# Rails erb alterantive to fields_for find specific record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm new to rails, and trying to modify an existing application.

I have a model that has a 'has_many' relationship with another type of record 'group_parameters'.  Group parameters has two fields (name and value).

I currently have a form that scopes group_parameters and prints all the stored records.  This is achieved by doing

`<%= f.fields_for group_parameters do | builder |  %>
     Attribute <%= builder.text_field(:name) %>
 <% end %>`

Instead I'd like to only display certain records where the name field equals a specific string.
Is there a simple method to help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= f.fields_for group_parameters, @specific_records do | builder | %> 
    Attribute <%=   builder.text_field(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

Fetch data from DB as per your criteria and assign to @specific_records