# Rails 4: Create multiple (different) entries from one form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, multiple-entries

I have a form that is used to create entries my model `ConsultStat`.  I would like to be able to enter multiple entries in one form, then have my controller separate them and save them to the database individually.

I am using jQuery to add additional rows to the form.  I replicate everything within the `<div class="form-group">` seen below.

I am using a `form_tag` since I assume `form_for` won't work (seems to only accept last entry if multiple are given.

**Form**

```
<%= form_tag add_multiple_stats_path do %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
    <!-- This section gets replicated with jQuery -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <%= label_tag :employee, "Employee" %>
                <%= select("consult_stat", "employee_id", @employees.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {include_blank: true}, style: "width:100%") %>
                <%# input :employee_id, as: :select, collection: Employee.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id %><br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <%= label_tag :consults, "Consults" %>
                <%= number_field_tag :consults, nil, class: "form-input", label: "Consults" %><br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <%= label_tag :signed, "Signed" %>
                <%= number_field_tag :signed, nil, class: "form-input" %><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- END section that gets replicated with jQuery -->
    </div>

    <%= submit_tag "Submit Consultation Stats" %>
<% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
post "/add_multiple_stats" => "consult_stats#add_multiple_stats", as: :add_multiple_stats
```

**Controller**

```
def add_multiple_stats
    @employees = Employee.all
    params["consult_stat"].each do |stat|
        puts stat
        # there is only 1 entry showing, even if I submit multiple entries
    end
end
```

Comment: You should user nested_form. Please have a look at below links  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html  and http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: I guess I don't understand how that will help me generate multiple entries at once

Comment: Ok. Let me ask you want to generate multiple entries of same type of model or different model? Is multiple entries are child of parent form?

Comment: Ok i got it as you mentioned in title that you want different entries

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978555/rails-erb-alterantive-to-fields-for-find-specific-record/27002802#27002802

Comment: Im still not sure how that is relevant.  I have a simple model and I'd like to be able to generate multiple entries, with different data, at once.

Comment: I get to the point where my params are `"consult_stat"=>{"iter_0"=>{"employee_id"=>"1", "consults"=>"7", "signed"=>"8"}, "iter_1"=>{"employee_id"=>"2", "consults"=>"6", "signed"=>"8"}` but I see the error `unpermitted parameter: iter_0, iter_1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124467/discussion-between-jagdish-and-jeremy-thomas).